# CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - but php sets header file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know that there are serveral questions about cors have been aksed/answered... But I did not find a solution for my issue...

I receive the following error message in my js application (based on jquery/jquery mobile):

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mydomain.de/api.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xyz' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500

PHP file starts with:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");    // cache for 1 day
...
```

Part of the js code:

```
$.ajax({
 type:      'POST',
 crossDomain: true,    
 cache:         false,
 url:       "http://www.mydomain.de/api.php",
 data:      payload,
 dataType:  'json',
 success:   function(a,b,c) { }
});
```

The php page is hosted at strato.de / php version 5.7

Any solution?

Comment: have you passed withCredentials?

Comment: Here is example of it -> http://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request

Comment: also first try to do things in FF, as chrome is a little bit more strick about CORS requests, or try no security chrome option

Comment: yes, I tried with credentials (right now)... no changes. Sorry & thx

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)", your script probably didn't even run.

Comment: have you tried jsonp and/or FF browser?

Comment: according to dr google, the error 500 represents a collection of multiples errors and I receive the detail information concerning the cross domain stuff... 
And actually locally (appache web server) it works perfect.

Comment: SOLVED.... Thanks to Antti and Parag/Jijo!

Issue: the script did not run correctly (timeout) with PHP 5.7 (lower PHP version at home worked).

I do not now why: The timeout was only "visible" using jsonp*, using cors I received almost immediatly the error mentioned above...

Based on your comments: I tried jsonp, noticed the issue (&fixed it) and back to cors...

Thanks a LOT!

* for two services I need to upload 100k, therefore I cannot use jsonp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataType as JsonP

```
 dataType: 'jsonp'
```

Then you dont get the error

Comment: unfortunately I have (want to) transfer sometimes up to 100k... jsonp would not work since the URL would get too long (if the response is large, it is certainly perfect)

Answer (score 0):

In your project, find the file web.config file. (I'm working in laravel, I find the file in public route, you get it in different path), Now add the following code after `<system.webServer>`

```
<httpProtocol>  
    <customHeaders>  
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />  
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />  
    </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>
```

[Screenshot: write code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02sVG.png)

I think this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the first solution doesn't work, then another solution is:
Open you antivirus, find out '**virus chest**' option and look for the file **'server.php'** in the list and if you find this file then apply **restore and add exception**.